Sci-Fi movie about a shapeshifter
I've seen a small portion of this movie roughly 15 years ago. Unfortunately, I was really young and can't really remember a lot of the details. I'd be really happy if you could help me identify it.

People are out in the wilderness, they set up a camp
They return to it and see their camp destroyed by what they think must have been a bear
The shapeshifter turns into a person that's been killed
They face the shapeshifter in a labyrinth-like ruin where it hid
It's revealed that the shapeshifter's looks are influenced by people's thoughts
They kill the shapeshifter by thinking of it dying from electricity
After their trip, when one of the characters is back at home, the shapeshifter reappears in front of the window in the form in which they killed it

It was in color and I think that it looked a little dated, even at the time, so I'd date it roughly to the 1980s. 
Again, because I was very young, some of the details could be different. The place where they were facing the shapeshifter could've been a normal house that was just too complicated for my young mind.

The creature reminds me a little bit of the creature in Forbidden Planet, whose appearance was also influenced by the protagonists.

Welcome to Movies & TV!  Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in?   Descriptions  or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

From the first 4 points I was going to suggest The Thing (1982) but from then on they start to become less of a match...
